# Run a batch script after the replit ends

Tags: python, replit

I use replit to host a python bot and every day or few hours it goes down
I get the error `access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access`

I want to run a batch script when the replit ends

with the code:
`kill 1`

is this possible and, if so, how?

Comment: A Discord bot using the legitimate Discord API shouldn't be running up against CloudFlare unless you're trying to DoS Discord. What exactly are you running that's tripping up their spam filters?

Comment: it errors at the line bot/client.run(TOKEN) and I use nextcord python